# WebGL Uniform Argument Type

Tags: glsl, pixi.js

I am attempting to write a WebGL image filter using the [PixiJS](http://pixijs.com/) library.  My filter should take an array of arrays, where each inner array represents a possible pixel color.  The function will then decide which element in the outer array to use.

I have managed to write a simple GLSL function which takes a *single* color array as a "uniform" argument, however I can't figure out how to pass the nested array.  Could you point me to the proper type declaration to accept a nested array of floats from this snippet?

```js
var fragmentSrc = [
  "uniform vec4 colorList;", // WHAT TYPE DO I NEED HERE TO PASS THE ARRY IN THE COMMENT BELOW?
  "void main() {",
  "  float GrayScale =  (gl_FragCoord.r * 299.0 / 1000.0) + (gl_FragCoord.g * 587.0 / 1000.0) + (gl_FragCoord.b * 114.0 / 1000.0);",
  "  float sigmoidThreshold = 1.0 / (1.0 + pow(2.7182818284590452353602874713527, (-((GrayScale - 128.0) /32.0))));",
  "  gl_FragColor = colorList;",
  "}",
];

var renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(750, 750);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.view);
var stage = new PIXI.Container();

function CustomFilter(fragmentSource) {

  PIXI.Filter.call(this,
    null,
    fragmentSource
  );
}

CustomFilter.prototype = Object.create(PIXI.Filter.prototype);
CustomFilter.prototype.constructor = CustomFilter;

var bg = new PIXI.Graphics();
bg.drawRect(0, 0, 375, 375);
bg.endFill();
stage.addChild(bg);

var filter = new CustomFilter(fragmentSrc.join('\r\n'));
filter.uniforms.colorList = [1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0] // WANT TO PASS AN ARRAY OF ARRAYS LIKE: 
// [[1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0]]
bg.filters = [filter];

renderer.render(stage);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/4.5.1/pixi.min.js"></script>
```

```
var fragmentSrc = [
  "uniform vec4 colorList;", // WHAT TYPE DO I NEED HERE TO PASS THE ARRY IN THE COMMENT BELOW?
  "void main() {",
  "  float GrayScale =  (gl_FragCoord.r * 299.0 / 1000.0) + (gl_FragCoord.g * 587.0 / 1000.0) + (gl_FragCoord.b * 114.0 / 1000.0);",
  "  float sigmoidThreshold = 1.0 / (1.0 + pow(2.7182818284590452353602874713527, (-((GrayScale - 128.0) /32.0))));",
  "  gl_FragColor = colorList;",
  "}",
];
```

Comment: declare an array of vec4 in your shader, open the dev tools, put a break point to find out what 'filter.uniforms.colorList' looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the code to this

```
var fragmentSrc = `
  uniform vec4 colorList[10]; 
  void main() {
    float GrayScale =  (gl_FragCoord.r * 299.0 / 1000.0) + (gl_FragCoord.g * 587.0 / 1000.0) + (gl_FragCoord.b * 114.0 / 1000.0);
    float sigmoidThreshold = 1.0 / (1.0 + pow(2.7182818284590452353602874713527, (-((GrayScale - 128.0) /32.0))));
    gl_FragColor = colorList[9];
  }
`;

var filter = new CustomFilter(fragmentSrc);
console.log(filter.uniforms);
```

And it prints

[image: show console]

so this works

```
filter.uniforms.colorList = [
   1, 0, 0, 0,     // 0
   1, 1, 0, 0,     // 1
   0, 1, 0, 0,     // 2
   0, 1, 1, 0,     // 3 
   0, 0, 1, 0,     // 4
   1, 0, 1, 0,     // 5
   .5, 0, 0, 0,    // 6
   0, .5, 0, 0,    // 7
   1, 1, 0, 1,     // 8
   .5, .5, .7, 1., // 9
];
```

and this

```
filter.uniforms.colorList = new Float32Array([
   1, 0, 0, 0,     // 0
   1, 1, 0, 0,     // 1
   0, 1, 0, 0,     // 2
   0, 1, 1, 0,     // 3 
   0, 0, 1, 0,     // 4
   1, 0, 1, 0,     // 5
   .5, 0, 0, 0,    // 6
   0, .5, 0, 0,    // 7
   1, 1, 0, 1,     // 8
   .5, .5, .7, 1., // 9
]);
```

etc...

If you really want an array of arrays in JavaScript you can do this to make `ArrayBufferView`s into the larger array

```
const colorValues = [];
for (let i = 0; i < filter.uniforms.colorList.length; i += 4) {
  const buffer = filter.uniforms.colorList.buffer;
  const byteOffset = i * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT;
  const length = 4;
  colorValues.push(new Float32Array(buffer, byteOffset, length));
}
```

now you can set an array element like this

```
colorValues[9].set([1, 1, 0, 1]);
```

```js
var fragmentSrc = `
  uniform vec4 colorList[10]; // WHAT TYPE DO I NEED HERE TO PASS THE ARRY IN THE COMMENT BELOW?
  void main() {
    float GrayScale =  (gl_FragCoord.r * 299.0 / 1000.0) + (gl_FragCoord.g * 587.0 / 1000.0) + (gl_FragCoord.b * 114.0 / 1000.0);
    float sigmoidThreshold = 1.0 / (1.0 + pow(2.7182818284590452353602874713527, (-((GrayScale - 128.0) /32.0))));
    gl_FragColor = colorList[9];
  }
`;

var renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(750, 750);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.view);
var stage = new PIXI.Container();

function CustomFilter(fragmentSource) {

  PIXI.Filter.call(this,
    null,
    fragmentSource
  );
}

CustomFilter.prototype = Object.create(PIXI.Filter.prototype);
CustomFilter.prototype.constructor = CustomFilter;

var bg = new PIXI.Graphics();
bg.drawRect(0, 0, 375, 375);
bg.endFill();
stage.addChild(bg);

var filter = new CustomFilter(fragmentSrc);
const colorValues = [];
for (let i = 0; i < filter.uniforms.colorList.length; i += 4) {
  const buffer = filter.uniforms.colorList.buffer;
  const byteOffset = i * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT;
  const length = 4;
  colorValues.push(new Float32Array(buffer, byteOffset, length));
}

colorValues[9].set([1, 1, 0, 1]);

bg.filters = [filter];

renderer.render(stage);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/4.5.1/pixi.min.js"></script>
```